# Android Wear: How to Scale List View Image?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to create a list view where every item in the list has an Image on top of a line of text. My problem is that I cannot get the Image to be any larger than 40X40, without it obscuring the view of the text underneath it. Here is my xml file:

```
<com.thinksai.saicloud.WearableListItemLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/firefox"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:textColor="#000003"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <!--android:drawableTop="@drawable/firefox"/>-->
            <!--android:drawablePadding="2dp"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</com.thinksai.saicloud.WearableListItemLayout>
```

As you can see in the commented out lines of the Textview, I tried to use the "drawableTop" instead of the Imageview, but that didn't work either. The documentation for WearableListView.setMaximizeSingleItem (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.html) gives me the impression that Android Wear forces the list to show three items at a time, unless there is only one item in the list. Is this correct? Is there no work around to force the wear to show one item at a time, regardless of the number of items in the list?

NOTE: I don't set the text of the text view here in the xml, I do it programmatically.

Comment: Are you wanting the firefox image to grow as large as the list item bounds allows (allowing for space for the text underneath)?

Comment: What a really want is for every item in the list to fill up the screen

Comment: I haven't developed for Android W yet, but based on the documentation for setMaximizeSingleItem, you'll only get that behavior of having an item fill the entire list view if there is one item in your adapter.  Seems weird to me, but that's what it says.  Have you tried as a test just having one item in your adapter to see if that's what happens?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet because it wasn't what I was going for (i.e. only one item in the list)

Comment: Right - seems to defeat the purpose of having a list.