# How to force WearableListView.Adapter to redraw?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, wear-os

I have an Android Wear app that has a list of 10 items. In my MainActivity.onCreate() I set my listView adapter like this: `listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, items));` However, `items` is currently filled with dummy data (for debugging purposes) because the Wear sends a message to the paired phone to get the real data from the server. Once the phone sends a message back to the Wear with the appropriate data, I populate `items` with that data. No refresh/redraw occurs though. Not even if I call `listView.setAdapter()` again. I know that `items` is being updated correctly because once I scroll down the list, on the Wear, the real data is visible (thanks to the recycle views). Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter which in turn will notify your ListView to requery the data in the adapter and draw the refreshed items.

Comment: I tried that before, but got confused because I was trying to call it on my listView (which doesn't exist), instead of my adapter. Thanks for the help :) . Would you mind taking a look at another one of my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866487/android-wear-how-to-scale-list-view-image ?

Comment: Actually.... it's not working quite as I would like. The dummy data will stay visible, until I touch the screen....